# Session gives previous value

Tags: session, asp-classic, vbscript

I am setting a random value to a session object. The problem is that the first time my page loads, it does not show that value and on subsequent reloads it shows the previous step values. Like

- no value for first load,
- first value for second reload and so on.

My page is in VBScript using Classic ASP.

```
rndval=Int((count-min+1)*Rnd+min)
Session("rndval")=rndval+1
```

Then on another page I use

```
Response.Write(Session("rndval"))
```

Comment: post some codes what you've tried

Comment: Specifically, it'd be helpful to see at least the code that saves the random value to Session and the code that retrieves it.

Comment: Please post your code and I'm sure somebody on stack will immediately see what's happening. Where and when are you assigning the random value (number? Guid?), and why? Thx.

Comment: rndval=Int((count-min+1)*Rnd+min)
Session("rndval")=rndval+1
Then on other page I did
Response.Write(Session("rndval"))